# Ruby on Rails with SimpleForm: Changing which data is sent when using :select or :collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have an object with a few fields on it - `name`, `code`, and of course, `id`.

Using the following code, my controller is receiving the `id` of the object that's selected (though name is what shows in the select dropdown).

```
<%= form.input :department_short, label: I18n.t('department'), wrapper_html: {class: 'header'},
                           placeholder: 'Select department', as: :collection_select, collection: @departments, required: false %>
```

What I'd like is to send up a different field (or, better, something based on one or more of these fields). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the value_method property together with lambda, like this:

```
<%= form.input :department_short, label: I18n.t('department'), :value_method => lambda {|t| "#{t.name} - #{t.code}"}, wrapper_html: {class: 'header'},
                           placeholder: 'Select department', as: :collection_select, collection: @departments, required: false %>
```

Like this, should be sent the "name - code" value from you object, for an example. In the lambda operation you can manipulate the value you get from the object as you want to. Hope you get the idea and this helps. Good luck!

EDIT:

From the official documentation (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

```
Collection inputs accept two other options beside collections:

label_method => the label method to be applied to the collection to retrieve the label (use this instead of the text_method option in collection_select)

value_method => the value method to be applied to the collection to retrieve the value
```

It also seems that if you have a method `to_label` on your model, it will use that method for labeling, so you don't have to put the label_method on every select you wanna use it. The doc doesn't mention if there's a similar `to_value` method but surely would be nice

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. While I have you here, is there a similar method for modifying the display names in the dropdown?

Comment: @ap Yeah, the label_method works as the same way, so you can use it to change the labels like that

Comment: You are such a prince. (It would be nice if these were in the official docs; or am I missing them somewhere?)

Comment: @ap they actually are, but it's not trivial how to use it with lambda... I'm gonna update my answer with some additional infos